# Concatenate type LPVOID with char *

Tags: c

I'm beginner in C programming language I got this code:

```
LPVOID lpvAddr;
lpvAddr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, strlen(jmp_esp), 0x3000, 0x40);
char *X = "\x41\x42\x43";
char *full2;
strcat(full2 , X);
strcat(full2 , lpvAddr);    //here I'm getting error because I can't concatenate char * with ipvAddr;
```

lpvAddr is containing memory address let's say : `00112233`.
How do I make `"full2"` variable contain: `"\x41\x42\x43\x00\x11\x22\x33"`

Comment: Where is `LPVOID` defined? It is unlikely you can convert this to a string. Perhaps using some variation of `sprintf(strIpvAddr, "<modifiers>", <whatever>)` can do it, but there's not enough information for that to help you.

Comment: full2 is a pointer. it contains the address of another memory location, it cannot contain what you suggest

Comment: Technically, `strcat(full2 , X);` isn't working either.

Comment: "*here I'm getting error*" are you sure you are using a C compiler and not a C++ compiler?

Comment: If you are beginning C programming, yoy should not be touching VirtualAlloc or LPVOID or any of the Windows-specific (censored).

Answer (score 1):

`VirtualAlloc` has very specific usage. Use `malloc` instead. Or use `VirtualAllocEx` if trying to access memory in another process.

Having said that, first you have to put something in `lpvAddr`. Put either zeros, bytes, or string. Example:

```
char *jmp_esp = "abc";
LPVOID lpvAddr;
lpvAddr = VirtualAlloc(NULL, strlen(jmp_esp)+1, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
strcpy(lpvAddr, jmp_esp);
```

Note you have to allocate 1 extra byte for the **`null-character`** at the end.

Next problem is `full2` which is uninitialized pointer. First you have to initialize, then use `strcpy` to write in to empty string, then use `strcat` to add another string to a **`NUL terminated string`**.

```
const char *X = "xyz";
char *full2 = malloc(strlen(x) + strlen(jmp_esp) + 1);
strcpy(full2 , X);
strcat(full2 , lpvAddr);
```

This should end with `VirtualFree` and `free` for `malloc` allocation.

Comment: Why the cast `strcpy((char*)lpvAddr, ... `? In C there is *no need* to cast from/to `void`-pointers?

Comment: @alk Thanks, I got that mixed it up with c++ again. I edited the post and removed the cast.

Comment: Another nitpick: C-String aren't NULL-terminated, but NUL-terminated. `NUL` is not the same as `NULL`. The former is the character `'\0'` and latter is the null-pointer literal. The `0` to terminate a C-string is common referred to as null-character. Please note capitalisation and number of Ls is by intention. I know it is not as consistent as it could be.

Comment: @alk I knew that didn't sound right as I was writing it. I think I finally got it in the edit!